# React-Native Picker problem - handle switch items

Tags: javascript, react-native, state, picker

I have problem with a Picker picker component.
so as u see there is a curriences array with strings. Im using Picker to choose some between them and I have function what is included to `onValueChange` prop in Picker, and then comes my problem with selecting an item from picker.

Firstly I can choose a whatever item from picker, but when I want to choose again I have just this choosed item before in the list:
[multiple items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VR4CA.png)
then i choosed for example EUR. When I want to choose a item again I have just this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tPHR.png)

Also when I change first picker item - it changes also in the second picker... don't know why.

also adding whole code here:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, TextInput, Picker} from 'react-native';
class CurrencyCashScreen extends React.Component {
  state = {
    currencies: ['USD', 'AUD', 'SGD', 'PHP', 'EUR'],
    base: 'PLN',
    amount: '',
    convertTo: 'EUR',
    result: '',
    date: '',
  };

  handleSelect = (itemValue, itemIndex) => {
    this.setState(
      {
        ...this.state,
        currencies: [itemValue],
        result: null,
      },
      this.calculate,
    );
  };

  handleInput = text => {
    this.setState(
      {
        ...this.state,
        amount: text,
        result: null,
        date: null,
      },
      this.calculate,
    );
  };

  calculate = () => {
    const amount = this.state.amount;
    if (amount === isNaN) {
      return;
    } else {
      fetch(`https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=${this.state.base}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
          const date = data.date;
          const result = (data.rates[this.state.convertTo] * amount).toFixed(4);
          this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            result,
            date,
          });
        });
    }
  };

  handleSwap = e => {
    const base = this.state.base;
    const convertTo = this.state.convertTo;
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState(
      {
        ...this.state,
        convertTo: base,
        base: convertTo,
        result: null,
      },
      this.calculate,
    );
  };
  render() {
    const {currencies, base, amount, convertTo, result} = this.state;
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>
          {amount} {base} is equevalent to
        </Text>
        <Text>
          {amount === '' ? '0' : result === null ? 'Calculating...' : result}{' '}
          {convertTo}
        </Text>
        <View>
          <View>
            <View>
              <TextInput
                keyboardType="numeric"
                value={amount}
                onChangeText={this.handleInput}
              />
              <Picker
                selectedValue={base}
                value={base}
                onValueChange={this.handleSelect}>
                {currencies.map((currency, index) => (
                  <Picker.Item label={currency} value={currency}>
                    {currency}
                  </Picker.Item>
                ))}
              </Picker>
            </View>
            <View>
              <TextInput
                editable={false}
                value={
                  amount === ''
                    ? '0'
                    : result === null
                    ? 'Calculating...'
                    : result
                }
              />
              <Picker
                selectedValue={convertTo}
                value={convertTo}
                onValueChange={this.handleSelect}>
                {currencies.map(currency => (
                  <Picker.Item label={currency} value={currency}>
                    {currency}
                  </Picker.Item>
                ))}
              </Picker>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View>
            <Text onClick={this.handleSwap}>CLICK ME</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default CurrencyCashScreen;
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `handleSelect` function you're overriding the `currencies` stored in state with a list containing only the selected currency. You should stop doing that.

Why not set a `selectedCurrency` value in state and use that for populating the picker with the current value, and update that when calling `handleSelect`?

**Updated to add more help**

When you initialise your state, you set the currencies as follows:

```
state = {
    currencies: ['USD', 'AUD', 'SGD', 'PHP', 'EUR'],
```

When your `handleSelect` function gets called, it changes this list in state:

```
handleSelect = (itemValue, itemIndex) => {
    this.setState(
      {
        ...this.state,
        currencies: [itemValue], // <-- HERE! You're changing the list of currencies
        result: null,
      },
      this.calculate,
    );
  };
```

After this gets called, your list of currencies is just the one you selected in your picker.

This is why when your component re-renders all the other options vanish:

You get the currencies out of state, and now its just an array containing the one you picked:

```
const {currencies, base, amount, convertTo, result} = this.state;
```

So in your picker when you call `currencies.map` to create the `Picker.Item` components, you only have one currency.

The next big issue is that you're calling the same `handleSelect` function from each picker ... so you can't actually pick two different currencies.

**Fixes:**

First, we need two handle functions for your two pickers:

```
handleSelectBase = base => this.setState({ base }, this.calculate)
handleSelectConvertTo = convertTo => this.setState({ convertTo }, this.calculate)
```

Then update your two pickers to use the correct handler function, and you should be in a better position.

Comment: Is there any chance to get more help? I mean this, can you show me how to do it?

Comment: Thank you Jon. It works now and everything is clearly for me now :)